# одинаковые строки в базе Oracle как изменить одно поле во всех строках кроме первой

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть одинаковые строки в базе Oracle как изменить одно поле во всех строках кроме первой пример[image: снимок]

надо изменить столбец DS_HAR c 0 на 3 при условии что первая запись должна остаться 0 а только след. меняются. И соблюдается условие что поле DS у них одиноковое

Comment: А что такое "первая запись", при какой сортировке она первая (без сортировки порядок записей не гарантируется)

Comment: И плюс к этому не ясно, что означает "DS у них одинаковое". Это DS заранее известно или его можно/нужно получить из какой то определенной записи (например, из той самой "первой"). Т.е. какие именно записи на картинке должны быть изменены, вы выделили почему то первые 2. но ведь первая не меняется, а у 4й DS такой же как у первых двух ...

Comment: Заменить все на 3, а потом одну (с указанием сортировки, при которой она "первая") обратно на 0.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что без дополнительных уточнений от ТС он бесполезен для кого либо, а ТС не ответил ни на один уточняющий комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно,

```
update T 
set    ds_har=3
where  dostor > (select min(doctor) from T T1 where T.ds=T1.ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update T 
set    ds_har=3
where  tkey not in (
         select tkey 
         from   (
                  select tkey 
                  from   T 
                  order  by .....(условие сортировки))
                  where  rownum =1 
               ) and доп условия
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - апдейт по rowid, вытащив все записи, кроме первой (правда, как уже говорили ранее, нужно понимать, что означает "первый")

```
update t
 set ds_har = 3
 where rowid in (
     select row_id from
     (select rowidtochar(rowid) as row_id, row_number () over (order by ...) as rn from t)
      where rn > 1)
```